# Convert Query Oracle to Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, postgresql-9.5

In Oracle

```
(select regexp_substr('a,,b','[^,]+', 1, level) 
 from dual 
 connect by regexp_substr('a,,b', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null);
```

it gives me output

```
a
b
```

In Postgresql

```
select regexp_split_to_table( 'a,,b',',');
```

it gives me output

```
a

b
```

It gives a blank row between `a` and `b`.
Can anyone please suggest how I can get output like `Oracle`.

Comment: Also I used select unnest(string_to_array('a,,b', ','));
get same output like a blank row between a and b but in oracle it doesnot give any blank row.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: There is an empty row between `a` and `b` (you can see double line, and `<tr><td></td></tr>` in markup). OP doesn't want it.

Answer (score 0):

In oracle you were searching for matches, not splitting. Doing the same in Postgres:

```
SELECT m[1] FROM regexp_matches('a,,b', '[^,]+', 'g') AS T(m);
```

EDIT: Thanks to a_horse_with_no_name and TimBiegeleisen for making me notice it was returning an array in each row.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple splitting/unnesting like that, string_to_array would be a better choice. Processing regular expressions is quite expensive.

If you put the set returning function into the FROM clause (where it should be) you can filter out the empty rows:

```
SELECT t.m
FROM unnest(string_to_array('a,,b', ',')) as t(m)
where nullif(trim(t.m),'') is not null;
```

`nullif(trim(t.m),'')` will also handle inputs like `a,   ,b` and treat the empty string as null.

Online example: https://rextester.com/VDWUEM85289